# PhpStorm database connection error

Tags: php, xampp, phpmyadmin, phpstorm

I get such error when making connection to the database in PhpStorm. I couldn't find a solution.

> Server returns invalid timezone. Go to 'Advanced' tab and set 'serverTimezone' property manually.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here you have an anwser 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql

Summarizing:
go to your msql console and type:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone;
```

to check that time zone is set

if you have no zone selected do it by e.g:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+2:00';
```

once its set go to your DataGrip into Advanced section (on the left from the General on your screenshot), and set it in the  **VM Options** edit text
like :

```
-Duser.timezone=UTC+2:00
```